# Applying a generic to a generic?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to enforce typings to match expected inputs of a function in a record, I have the following:

```
type ABC = {
    money: number;
}

type Inputs = {
    'abc': ABC
}

type Keyed = keyof Inputs

type ActionFunc = <T extends Keyed>(T, arg: Inputs[T]) => string;

const ActionMappings: Record<Keyed, ActionFunc>  = {
    abc: (inputIsNotDefinedAsABC) => {
        return 'I would like it to be defined'
    }
}
```

Typescript is not enforcing that the input for ABC is type 'ABC' and instead infers it as an 'any'.

Have tried a few variations of the above but the fundamental problem I think is that I haven't worked out how to get TS to understand the generic function should be constrained in the Record.

The only way I can get it to work is to be explicit:

```
const ActionMappings  = {
    abc: (definedAsABC: ABC) => {
        return 'kind of works'
    }
}

ActionMappings[abc](/* accepts payload only in ABC type*/)
```

Comment: `<T extends Keyed>(T, arg: Inputs[T]) => String` is not what you think it is.  That first `T` is a dummy parameter identifier and not a type; it is equivalent to `<T extends Keyed>(T: any, arg: Inputs[T]) => String`.  Don't you get a compiler warning of the form `Parameter has a name but no type. Did you mean 'arg0: T'?(7051)` from that? So, what are you trying to do with that type? (aside: `String` is also probably not what you think it is; you should use `string` unless you have some strange requirements)

Comment: Possibly [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Na2JBm) is what you're trying to do, but it requires that `ActionFunc` be a generic type of a specific function, and not the specific type of generic function.  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz that was it, thank you! if you put that down as an answer I'm happy to tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your use case it looks like you want:

```
type ActionFunc<K extends Keyed> = (arg: Inputs[K]) => string;

const ActionMappings: { [K in Keyed]: ActionFunc<K> } = {
    abc: (x) => {
        // (parameter) x: ABC     
        return x.money.toFixed(2); // okay
    }
}
```

Compare my version `type ActionFunc<K extends Keyed> = (arg: Inputs[K]) => string` to (a modified/corrected rendition of) your version `type OrigActionFunc = <K extends Keyed>(arg: Inputs[K]) => string`.  You can see that both involve a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `K`, but the scopes of the type parameters differ.

In my version, `ActionFunc<K>` is itself generic.  That is, you can't talk about `ActionFunc` without specifying `K`.  Once you *do* specify `K` (e.g., as `"abc"`), then `ActionFunc<"abc">` is *not* a generic function type (e.g., `(arg: ABC) => string`).  You want each member of type `K` of the `ActionMappings` object to accept only the corresponding argument of type `Inputs[K]` (note that this leads naturally to a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over every key `K` in `Keyed`).  *You* want to be in charge of `K`, not *callers* of the functions.

This differs from your version in which `OrigActionFunc` was a specific type (no type parameter necessary to talk about it) corresponding to a generic function, where *callers* specify the type parameter, not *you*.  Such a function would need to accept every possible type parameter; you'd have no control over which argument type was passed into the functions.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQgYSgXigbwFBW1AtgewDsIQAuKQgV1wCMIAnAbgwF8MNRIoBJQsS4AGcU6LDgDkAQxoBjceXgJW7TtADSJCABMRAaxL4AZjz4DBK8NBgzgASyIAxSoRkAeNVAgAPYBEJbhDRBtAD4RAApJegBzcl5+IQBtNQBdAEoUMMFgeltCaOYMGSJs2Bt7QgBZSTAwPOjBcjQoZKg8qCDtFIVyx2c3NTCWEUwcKGkZcnCvDOQw0bGcAHolqHCwKMlcCF96DK8FREWxRah6Hcp6QigvADoCYhBb4HwHWy9tcIAmNMYoFag+F0khAJygbDYQA)

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps you

```
type ABC = {
  money: number;
};

type Inputs = {
  abc: ABC;
};

type ActionMappingsType = {
  [K in keyof Inputs]: (arg: Inputs[K]) => String;
};

const ActionMappings: ActionMappingsType = {
  abc: (arg: ABC) => {
    return 'ABC';
  },
};

const abc = ActionMappings.abc({ money: 1 });

console.log(abc);
//ABC
```